# How can I drop a variant sandbox in MKS after the related developement path was removed

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

I removed a development path in MKS and now I want to remove/delete the sandbox I created for it. In the UI I cannot drop a sandbox without opening it first, but I cannot open variant sandbox once their dev path was removed. In the command line interface "si dropsandbox" also reports an error related to the existence of the dev path. Any other suggestions?

Update: Here is the error I get when trying to open the sandbox:

> MKS125319: For subproject proj1/proj1.pj the variant subproject on development path proj1_experimental cannot be accessed because it is not part of the current project configuration and is not eligible to be accessed from the specified configuration: MKS125226: The development path proj1_experimental does not exist in the specified project.

Comment: what is the problem when you try to drop the sandbox from the UI?

Comment: It seems that to drop a sandbox it needs to be open and then I can go to Sandbox -> Drop. But in my case because the development path does not exist anymore I cannot open the sandbox. Unless there is another way the drop a sandbox from the UI?

Answer (score 2):

The key for dropping your sandbox is to set the delete option to "nothing". This will prevent the MKS client from doing any project lookup on the server.

You can drop from the graphical client by right clicking on the "My Sandboxes" window, or from the command line:

```
si dropsandbox --delete=none c:\mysandbox\project.pj
```

Answer (score 0):

other option is to delete the sandbox directly using windows explorer, not the MKS GUI. important is to have the .pj file removed, then the sandbox will be ignored by MKS at all in its GUI.